# Dynamic programming algorithm for unweighted interval scheduling?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I was wondering if someone could please help me reason about a DP algorithm for unweighted interval scheduling.

I'm given 2 arrays [t1,...,tn] and [d1,...,dn] where ti is the start time of job i and di is the duration of job i. Also the jobs are sorted by start time, so t1 <= t2 <= ... <= tn. I need to maximize the number of jobs that can be executed without any overlaps. I'm trying to come up with a DP algorithm and runtime for this problem. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know for a fact that a DP algorithm exists? Like in a "design a DP algorithm" homework?

Comment: Yep, this is a question from a past final exam I'm preparing for

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I don't have any more time now to spend on this problem. Here is an idea, I think it lends itself nicely to Dynamic Programming. [Actually I think it **is** DP, but almost two decades have passed since I last studied such things...]

Suppose `T = {t1, t2, ..., tn}` is partitioned as follows:

```
T = {t1, t2, ..., tn} = {t1, t2, ..., tk} U {tk+1, tk+2, ..., tn}
  = T1(k) U T2(k)
```

Let `T2'(k)` be the subset of `T2(k)` **not containing** the jobs overlapping `T1(k)`.

Let `opt(X)` be the optimal value for a subset `X` of `T`. Then

```
opt(T) = min( opt( T1(k) ) + opt( T2'(k) )
```

where the minimum is taken along any possible `k in {1, 2, ..., n}`

Of course you need to compute `opt()` recursively, and take into account overlaps.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest for me to think about if I suppose that you work out what the end time would be for each job and sort the jobs into order of increasing end time, although you can probably achieve the same thing using start times working in the opposite direction.

Consider each job in order of increasing end time. For each job work out the maximum number of jobs you can handle up to and including that job if you decide to work on that job. To work this out, look at the answers you have already computed that cover times up to the start time of that job and find the one that covers the maximum number of jobs. The best you can do while handling the job you are considering is one plus that maximum number.

When you have considered all the jobs, the maximum number you can cover is the maximum number you have computed when considering any job. You can work out which jobs to do by storing the previous job that you identified when working out the maximum score possible for a particular job, and then tracing these pointers back from the job with the maximum score.

With N jobs to consider you look back at at most N previously computed answers when working out the best possible score for each job so I think this is O(N^2)